# Syntactic sugar for making new dictionary entries + other operations in Gforth

Tags: forth, gforth

I am a Forth newbie, trying to develop some (pseudo useful) toys to learn the language. I want to make the following operations condensed:

```
[ifundef] vehicles    2variable vehicles [then]
[ifundef] cars<       2variable cars<    [then]
vehicles 2@ s" cars "    s+ vehicles 2!
cars<    2@ s" vehicles" s+ cars<    2!
```

by the following (much more compact) instruction

```
-> vehicles cars
```

Or, in other words:

- "->" parse the two following names
- for the first name create a dictionary entry "vehicle" for a 2variable like structure, if it doesn't already exists, a string will be assigned to it
- for the second name create another entry "cars<" (note the <), if it doesn't already exists, also a 2variable
- then add (not replace) the string "cars" to variable vehicle
- and add the string "vehicles" to variable cars<

I made an hack to obtain just this behavior using strings manipulation and evaluating...

```
: space+ ( str -- ) s"  " s+ ;
\ use like: cars add alfa-romeo (first is a 2variable name, second a parsed name)
: add ( a "name" -- ) dup >r 2@ parse-name space+ s+ r> 2! ;

create _x 256 chars allot align
: _x@ ( -- ) _x count ;
: _x! ( -- ) _x place ;

create _y 256 chars allot align
: _y@ ( -- ) _y count ;
: _y! ( -- ) _y place ;

: init_x ( str -- ) 2dup s" [ifundef] " 2swap s+ s"  2variable " s+ 2swap s+ s"  [then]" s+ evaluate ;
: init_y ( str -- ) 2dup s" [ifundef] " 2swap s+ s" < 2variable " s+ 2swap s" <" s+ s+ s"  [then]" s+ evaluate ;

: make-dictionary-entries ( -- ) _x@ init_x    _y@ init_y ;
: add-strings-to-entries  ( -- ) _x@ s"  add "  s+ _y@ s+ evaluate
                                 _y@ s" < add " s+ _x@ s+ evaluate ;

: -> parse-name _x! parse-name _y!
     make-dictionary-entries
     add-strings-to-entries ;



\ CUSTOM TESTING to improve readability of the examples
: test( POSTPONE assert( ; immediate
: true! 0= throw ;
: false! throw ;
: same-string! str= true! ;

-> vehicles cars
test( vehicles 2@  s" cars "     same-string! )
test( cars< 2@     s" vehicles " same-string! )

-> vehicles trucks
-> vehicles dreams
test( vehicles 2@  s" cars trucks dreams " same-string! )
test( trucks< 2@   s" vehicles "           same-string! )

-> cars ferrari
-> cars lamborghini
-> dreams lamborghini
test( cars 2@          s" ferrari lamborghini " same-string! )
test( lamborghini< 2@  s" cars dreams "         same-string! )
```

I think another more direct, more elegant way exists, but this is the best I can do at this time. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer (for now at least), but ***defining words*** may or may not be a part of a solution (`CREATE`, `DOES>`). See e.g. [chapter 11 in *Starting Forth*](https://www.forth.com/starting-forth/11-forth-compiler-defining-words/). As Leo Brodie says in that chapter, *"We have just extended our compiler!"* and *"we've shown two ways to extend the Forth compiler: Add new, specialized compilers, by creating new defining words. Extend the existing colon compiler by creating new compiling words."*.

Comment: `: -> create 0 , create 0 , ;` this will take care of creating 2 2variables like structures using create, the problem is I don't know how to get the names used by `create` back and use them also as strings.

Comment: Regarding `same-string!` and similar names — usually, by convention, exclamation mark in the name means **store**. So `some!` can mean to store into _some_ variable or store _some_ type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Some pieces of advice

1. Start top-down decomposition from a pure postfix solution.
2. Find some kind of *ideal* **conceptual** implementation of the top-level postfix solution.
3. Implement the absent words and-or levels of your Forth-system.

NB: It is not the general rules, but some weak points from the code in the question.

One common rule is following.
In the plumbing part the postfix syntax should be only used. The prefix syntax (parsing words) may take place as sugar on the top level only. I.e. any parsing word should have a postfix variant.

A general postfix solution for the given problem is: `S" content" S" name" update-var`

#### The solution

```
\ reference implementations of some underlying words for testing purpose only
: s, ( d-txt -- ) here swap dup allot move ;
: s+ ( d-txt1 d-txt2 -- d-txt3 ) here >r 2swap s, s, r> here over - 0 c, ;
: s+! ( d-txt addr -- ) dup >r 2@ 2swap s+ r> 2! ; \ '+!' naming convention 
: gs+ ( d-txt1 -- d-txt2 ) s"  " s+ ; \ add gap string ('space+' is too long)
\ some Forth-systems have these words as factors:
: created ( d-txt-name -- ) s" create " 2swap s+ evaluate ;
: obey ( i*x d-txt-name wid -- j*x true | i*x d-txt-name false )
  >r 2dup r> search-wordlist if nip nip execute true exit then  false
;

\ the solution itself

wordlist constant v \ for special auto-created variables

: make-var ( d-txt-name -- addr )
  get-current >r v set-current
  created here 0 , 0 ,
  r> set-current
;
: obtain-var ( d-txt-name -- addr )
  v obey if exit then  make-var
;
: update-var ( d-txt-content d-txt-name -- )
  obtain-var s+!
;
: -> \ "vehicles" "cars"
  parse-name parse-name
  2over gs+ 2over s" <" s+ update-var
  gs+ 2swap update-var
;
```

`d-` prefix in the stack notation symbols here means a two-cells value, and `d-txt-` prefix means a string (cell-pair).

`s,` *( d-txt -- )* stores given string into the data space as is (see also [`,`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/Comma) and [`c,`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/CComma)); NB: in Gforth it stores in counted string format (see [3.1.3.4 Counted strings](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#subsubsection.3.1.3.4)).

`created` is a postfix variant of [`create`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/CREATE) (in a proper system the last should be defined via the first); regarding etymology see also the standard words [`included`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/INCLUDED) (postfix form) and [`include`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/INCLUDE) (prefix form, parsing word).

Also it is better to use a separate wordlist for these auto-created variables to avoid possible issues on clash names (e.g. what if you need `-> here str`). See the variant without a separate wordlist in the [revision 8](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48533931/8).

To write testcases the well-known [ttester.fs](https://github.com/gerryjackson/forth2012-test-suite/blob/master/src/ttester.fs) library can be also used (in Gforth it is located in ./test/ directory). In this library `->` word is defined for its own purpose, so the synonyms can be used to overcome undesired shadowing.

Comment: It looks like exactly what I was looking for, but it give me errors... Please see my edited question. It seems like a string get corrupted or some other memory problem. Tested in gforth 0.7.3

Comment: Initially `s,` word definition was left for self-study. But it turns out that Gforth has such word with different behavior.  So, I have added the intended definition into my answer.

Comment: It works, thanks. If I don't ask too much, can you recommend me a good book or website about forth beyond starting and thinking forth?

Comment: There are plenty resources of starting level, tutorials, papers, and even guides to design a Forth-system ([ForthHub](https://github.com/ForthHub/discussion/issues/) can be used for discussion), but I don't know other better Forth-related book regarding how to think and create programs at whole.

Comment: @Vasily: I can recommend "Forth - A Text and Reference" by Mahlon G. Kelly and Nicholas Spies. ISBN 0133263312/978-0133263312. It is out of print, but it should possible to lend it from a library (that is what I did many years ago).